# Getting ALL Protein entries from Entrez for a particular taxonomic id

Tags: sequence, entrez, biopython, efetch

I'm trying to get ALL Proteins for a Taxonomic ID from Entrez using Esearch/Efetch and the following command:

```
esearch -db "protein" -query "txid374666[Organism]" | efetch -format fasta > txid_374666.fasta
```

Can somebody tell if this command will get ALL proteins or not? Besides, this appears to be a bit slow.

Can somebody point out any Biopython workflow, particularly how to get ALL Proteins

Thanks

Comment: That would work - except for the precise search term used. The issue is the NCBI server may time out, certainly if this was Blast it would do. Doing a single command line would prevent checking. Personally I would use a script to check what was downloaded with the `esearch` output (which will certainly work). If I get chance I will provide a full answer, e.g. search term stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll await your answer

Comment: I've to download a huge lot of sequences for hundreds of bacterial genus (not species)  for a metaproteomics study. Which method will work best for me? esearch/efetch, python scripting , anything else?

Comment: If I've time I will answer in detail about how I'd do this. In general further details would help (even if not me answering), i.e. how many different species are needed? This sounds like a script more than a one liner.

Comment: Around 700 genus are there, and under each jenus on an average 3 species. I'm trying to download using esearch/efetch . I belong to University, where I've good internet speed , yet, the link is breaking very often

Comment: Hi there, not sure if it can help but I asked a similar question some times ago here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74727918/handle-500-server-error-type-during-api-request-using-rentrez/75055203#75055203. I am using R however. General idea was that it was taking too long so I had to deal with server errors using a try/catch/sleep function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by somebody, the datasets tools from NCBI  is blazing fast:

```
datasets download genome taxon 187492  --include protein
```

[NCBI Datasets Tool](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/datasets/docs/v2/download-and-install/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, its really useful.

Comment: If you do get chance @TheAugust please mark your answer as "accepted" (helps with site stats). I recommend upvoting the answer because its efficiency allows local blast (and other methods) to interrogate data when remote NCBI blast is inefficient. NCBI servers do have a restricted access policy for some of their services.